# Add multiline html comment to layout by helper

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have this code:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString SetCopyRight(this HtmlHelper helper, Type type)
{
  StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();

  txt.AppendLine("<!--\n");

#if DEBUG
  txt.AppendLine($"({type.Assembly.GetName().Version} DEBUG\n");
#else
  txt.AppendLine($"{typeof(string).Assembly.GetName().Version}\n");
#endif

  txt.AppendLine($"Copyright(c) 2000 -  { DateTime.Now.Year}\n");
  txt.AppendLine($"Page created: { DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:sstt")}\n");

  txt.AppendLine("-->\n");

  return new MvcHtmlString(txt.ToString());
}
```

When I run the website I'd like to see:

```
<!--
1.0.0.7 DEBUG
Copyright(c) 2000 -  2020
Page created: 13 October 2020 10:30:30AM
-->
```

in the HTML.

For some reasone the browser shows it all in one line.
How can I get it like above?

Strange enough when I edit the HTML in de browsers developer tool (F12), it's showing the text on mulitple lines.

Comment: Try wrapping your info inside a div and applying white-space: pre-wrap `<div style="white-space: pre-wrap"></div>`

Comment: That would not work because it is between html comment tags. Html between those tags would not be rendered as html.

Comment: you are absolute right, can you add the code where the element gets rendered? because rendering you code doesnt display any information for me. I tried the pre-wrap solution without the comment tags and it works fine

Comment: It is not supposed to be visible on the page. It's just for us to check what version the site is by opening developer tools in de browser (F12).